# How to lint (statically analyze code for) magic numbers in Python?

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

Googling "pylint magic numbers" didn't return anything useful. Is there any way to lint Python code for [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))?

(I put [pylint](/questions/tagged/pylint) but the answer can be in any Python linter.)

Comment: How pervasive is the problem? Could a simple regex for floating-point and integer numbers suffice?

Comment: @blacksite Yeah I guess that would work as well.

Comment: In case you haven't seen [this](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1379) thread, I think it's safe to say that it's not supported by PyLint.

Comment: @SamGomena Actually that thread is the reason that I asked this question :)

Comment: It looks like there was a pull request for adding a magic number checker to pylint that was rejected but you can have a look at the proposal [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/1483) if you want to try to implement it yourself.   The author of that pull request also started a repo for developing a pylint extension [here](https://github.com/rogalski/pylint-magic) but as of now it doesn't look like they've actually started working on it. Maybe they'll get to it in the future if you want to keep an eye out

Comment: @blacksite:  just hunting for numbers with regex doesn't work.  You get all kinds of false positive from matches in comments and literal strings, and those really waste your time.  You need a full lexer, so it can accurately ignore things which are NOT numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to build a Python language tokenizer, and pick out all the constant-number tokens.

Our Source Code Search Engine does searches across language tokens from large sets of files, driven by language tokenizers (it has some 40 of these including Python 2 and 3).  One forms queries by stating constraints over sequences of tokens, such as

```
 I=*abc* '('
```

meaning "find identifiers containing the letters 'abc' followed by a left-paren token." and print out the found instances.  [Such queries automatically ignore white space and comment tokens]

The query you want could be stated as:

```
 N>2
```

meaning,  "find number tokens with value greater than 2" assuming 0 and 1 don't qualify as magic constants.  (IMHO they are as magic as others, but there is room to disagree, and I wanted to provide an example that wasn't completely trivial).

You can replicate this with a lexer generator (see "Flex") with some custom code on top that filters for number tokens.